# Adding a text stored in a variable to string to be saved to a text file

Tags: c#, string, variables

Hi I am trying to save text to a text file with some string, e.g. the students name added to it, but I'm a bit stuck

```
string iName2 = iName;
string text = "The student named {0} needs more work with plurals";
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Artificial_Intelligence_Project_3\WindowsFormsApplication1\Info.txt", text);`
```

Comment: what exactly are you stuck with? If you trying to add iName2 to "text", that won't work because it isn't referenced anywhere. Also, you cant use {0} as place holders without encasing them in a String.Format()

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming `iName` is the name. `String.Format` is the method you need:

```
string text = String.Format("The student named {0} needs more work with plurals", iName);
```

Unless you need `iName2` somewhere else, you do not need it.

Apart from being more readable, `String.Format` has one **advantage** over string concatenation with `+`. It allows you to **change the order** of substituted text fragments or *omit* some of them:

```
string text = String.Format("{0} {1}", a, b);

// changed order within text without changing argument order!
string text2 = String.Format("{1} {0}", a, b);
```

This is particularly useful if you're doing **localization**: Different languages have different rules to construct phrases, where the fragments may need to be substituted in different order.

Answer (score 1):

```
string text = "The student named " + iName2 + " needs more work with plurals";
```